# Hadoop Single Node : Permission Denied

Tags: hadoop

I just installed Hadoop single node but when i run it by logging on localhost it gives error that it cannot make changes to files as permission is denied?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed all the steps as suggested in: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/single_node_setup.html ?

You may want to look at this : http://getsatisfaction.com/cloudera/topics/permission_denied_error_in_desktop

Also, some more information would definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given necessary permissions.Make a different user other than root.Follow this tutorial to the point http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be missing permissions for the user on the directory containing the files

make sure that the user you are logged on , is the owner of the Hadoop directory by running 
`ls -la` command

if not the owner run the command `chown -R hadoop user:group hadoop` directory and it will work fine.

also you can follow the tutorial of michael noll

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/